# Is "Crude" a valid antonym of "Urbane"?

Tags: indian-english, antonyms

There was a question asked in an exam to find the antonym of "Urbane".

[image]

I don't understand how "Crude" is the antonym of "Urbane". Crude means raw, e.g. a food can be crude. I think "Rural" should be the correct antonym. Please tell me some official reference which mentions "Crude" or "Rural" as the antonym of "Urbane".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "refined" (as in "refined manners") is a synonym for "urbane" and the opposite of "refined" is "crude" (as in "crude behavior", i.e. rough or indelicate or discourteous).

Answer (score 3):

This exam question is designed to trick you if you confuse *urban* with *urbane.*

**Urban** means *having to do with cities*; **urbane** means *well-mannered or cultured.*

Comment: But how is "Crude" correct antonym of "Urbane"?

Comment: Crude can mean ill-mannered; consider [definition 3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crude)